# How can I add/set multiple IPs in Prometheus with different targets

Tags: yaml, prometheus

I am trying to simplify the Prometheus configuration so that when we add/remove servers, we can easily replace the IP address.

Here is my prometheus.yml file

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'MAP-map-health-test'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: /probe
    params:
      module: [prod-map-servers]
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - 'map-servers.yml'
    relabel_configs:
      - source_labels: [__address__]
        target_label: __param_target
      - source_labels: [__param_target]
        target_label: instance
      - target_label: __address__
        replacement: blackbox_exporter:9115
```

and here is my map-servers.yml

```
targets:
  - http://10.0.2.16
  - http://10.0.2.11
  - http://10.0.2.12
  - http://10.0.2.13
  - http://10.0.2.14
  - http://10.0.2.17
  - http://10.0.2.44
```

The above works if I only have to check the Apache service.

What I want to achive is I can add multiple checks with same IPs:

```
- 'map-server.yml'/test1.php
...
...
- 'map-server.yml'/test2.php
```

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "multiple checks with same IPs"? Do you mean multiple metrics end points in each target IP address?

Answer (score 0):

If you want alternative metric paths for the same set of IP addresses, you can just create another job using a different metric path:

```
scrape_configs:

  - job_name: 'MAP-map-health-test_probe-a'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: /probe-a
    params:
      module: [prod-map-servers]
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - 'map-servers.yml'
    relabel_configs:
      # ...

  - job_name: 'MAP-map-health-test_probe-b'
    scrape_interval: 5s
    metrics_path: /probe-b
    params:
      module: [prod-map-servers]
    file_sd_configs:
      - files:
        - 'map-servers.yml'
    relabel_configs:
      # ...
```

This will scrape `http://10.0.2.16/probe-a`, `http://10.0.2.16/probe-b`, `http://10.0.2.11/probe-a`, `http://10.0.2.11/probe-b`, etc.

If an IP address changes, it is reflected immediately in both jobs.